# How to use View just like div tag in Web Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Surly, in web project it is very obvious to use `div` like following:

```
<div>
  sample text
</div>
```

But, it is cause to error in `React Native`:

```
<View>
  sample text
</View>
```

How I can modify or wrap or anything else to use `View` like `div`?

Comment: your que is not clear. can u make it little more clear

Comment: You can only display text inside a Text component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am sure you have already discovered you cannot use `<div>` inside react-native. You have to use components that you construct from `<View>` and `<Text>`

If you want to display text on the screen then it must be wrapped inside Text tags.

So you could do something like this and it would display your text on the screen.

```
<View>
   <Text>sample text</Text>
</View>
```

Take a look at the documentation for react-native. They have many good examples https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

On their first page they show how to construct a simple component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

class HelloReactNative extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          If you like React, you'll also like React Native.
        </Text>
        <Text>
          Instead of 'div' and 'span', you'll use native components
          like 'View' and 'Text'.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The rest of their documentation is full of useful examples on how to set up and make your own components.

For a break down on some of the differences between React and React-Native see https://medium.com/appnroll-publication/switch-between-react-and-react-native-548267e1348a

Comment: Thanks for your answer. please upvote me, I'm under 15 and I cannot upvote your great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare a `div` indeed to a `View`, but there is a restriction that strings can only be displayed within a `Text` tag.

```
<View>
  <Text>sample text</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude, you're answer is right but I didn't reach to 15 reps to upvote you. please upvote my question that I reach to 15 and then upvote you.